# Save method in NSManagedObjectContext takes a long time if I assign the relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, performance, core-data

I have two different `NSManagedObjects` that I am trying to save to core data (100k-200k records each). List one has customers, and list two has projects. There is a to-many relationship between a customer and a project.

> If I loop on the projects and assign the customer relationship the
>   `[context save:]` method it takes forever (more than 8 minutes,
>   usually the app crashes out of memory before it finishes.)

If I comment the relationship assignment (for testing purpose, I need the relationship to be assigned at that point of the code.) then the `[context save:]` method would take an only couple of seconds. I am pretty sure core data can handle it in a better way, so what am I missing?

**Note: I put each object back to fault right after the assignment by calling [context refreshObject:] check https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html for further details **

```
NSManagedObjectContext* context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    context.parentContext = [self moc];

    [projectsJSON enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id projectJSON, BOOL *stop) {

        Project* project = [self Project* project = projectManagedObjectFromJSON:projectJSON inContext:context];

        //there's a dictionary of loaded customers in memory
        Customer *customer = customers[projectJSON[@"customer_primary_key"]];

        [customer addProjectsObject:project];
        project.customer = customer;
        [context refreshObject:customer mergeChanges:NO];
    }];
    /*if you comment the last three lines, save will take 1-2 seconds for 100k projects. It currently takes 8+ minutes*/
    [context save:&err];
```

I expect the `[context save:]` method not to but what happens is that it takes forever if I assign the relationship.

Comment: The "save" method inserts data in memory into database files so it is expected to be the time-consuming one. Still 8min really seems absurd. Maybe you could play with some settings on your model; some indexing may be going on that is hard to resolve. Otherwise (if possible) you could do without relations: Just store IDs of each others.

Comment: You are adding a project to the customer object `[customer addProjectsObject:project];`, then adding the customer to the project object `project.customer = customer;`. Is this not the same process repeated? Why do you call `refreshObject`?

Comment: @MaticOblak I ended up saving ids, and depending on custom getters to get the actual object when needed. Still feels it can be done without this hack, it can't be that CoreData can't handle such common usecase.

Comment: @andrewbuilder from my understanding you have to set the relationship and the inverse relationship yourself. - The fault for the customer managedObject fires at line  [customer addProjectsObject:project]  so I'm calling refreshObject to set the customer object back to fault as I no longer need it's attributes to be loaded in the memory.

Comment: 1. You set the relationship and inverse relationship only in the model (editor); 2. In code, you need only set the relationship once, usually from whatever entity you’re working with; 3. I’d recommend you do some more reading on faults; 4. Use `print()` to terminal and set breakpoints to actually interrogate your `Customer` entity - line by line - to see how it’s attribute and relationship values change after each of those 3 lines of code. You’ll also be able to observe whether the relationship/s are faulted or not. I’d be very surprised if you need the call to `refreshObject`.

Comment: @keriackus I just tried to simulate your situation. I created a fresh project with core data model of 2 items having one-to-many relation. I created 100 containers and then distributed 150000 items between them. The whole process took 5.439 seconds (includes generating objects, assigning stuff and random accessing...). I then fetched the containers back to do the sanity check and all looks OK. Maybe you should start the same way and see what is a minimum requirement to get the result you are seeing.

Comment: @andrewbuilder I actually used refreshObject method after reading throughly about faulting, and doing extensive debugging. The impact on memory was reduced significantly from 900 MB to 23 MB. As I mentioned in my last response to you the customer object is faulted until [customer addProject:] is executed. Check https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html

Regarding setting the inverse relationship you might be right. I anyways commented that line out and it's not the reason behind [context save] taking forever.

Comment: Very interesting re `refreshObject`. Regarding setting the inverse relationship, I am right. Surely you must see this during debugging? Regarding the duration of `save, why I have written comments and not an answer. It’s an attempt to help, not a criticism.

Comment: PS you should update your question with that information about `refreshObject` as it may help others better understand and/or figure out your problem with the call to save.